# ABP new project with v8 CLI, "abp install-libs" creates empty "libs" folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npm, .net-core, abp

I am trying to run ABP, so far it works for the most part just the AuthServer has no styling.
Running .NET Core 8 on macOS Sonoma

I installed npm and yarn both have the correct versions, I also ran the "abp install-libs" command with this output:

```
ABP CLI 8.0.2
Found 1 projects.
/Users/dennisrahmen/GitHub/DR.DIAS/Source/DR.DIAS.AuthServer
Running Yarn on /Users/dennisrahmen/GitHub/DR.DIAS/Source/DR.DIAS.AuthServer
yarn install v1.22.21
warning ../../package.json: No license field
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.03s.
```

Sadly that just creates an empty "libs" folder in the AuthServer project.
I already tried removing various lock files as well as rebuilding and reinstalling yarn npm.
So I have these errors while running the project:

```
[23:46:14 DBG] Added 0 entity changes to the current audit log
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/core/abp.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/v4-shims.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/toastr/toastr.min.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/select2/css/select2.min.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 DBG] Added bundle 'Basic.Global' to the page in 31,67 ms.
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/utils/abp-utils.umd.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/core/abp.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/jquery/jquery.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/jquery/abp.jquery.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/lodash/lodash.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/jquery-form/jquery.form.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/select2/js/select2.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/datatables.net-bs5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/toastr/toastr.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/luxon/luxon.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/luxon/abp.luxon.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/timeago/jquery.timeago.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/moment/moment.min.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 ERR] Could not find the bundle file '/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js' for the bundle 'Basic.Global'!
[23:46:14 DBG] Added bundle 'Basic.Global' to the page in 18,70 ms.
```

Comment: Did you check that your abp-cli and your abp project have the same version ?

Comment: @Manuel1234 how would I check this?
The CLI is 8.0.2 and the project ist running on .NET 8 so the packages are 8.0.1 since there is no 8.0.2 of .NET yet.

Comment: Check the version number of one abp package in a .csproj file. The packages start with Volo.Abp.

Comment: @Manuel1234 all of it is on 8.0.2 so the same version as the CLI.

Comment: okay fine. Try yarn install and after that try abp-install-libs.

Comment: Same problem, you can see in my post the first Code Block that yarn is installed in v1.22.21, I just ran it and `abp install-libs` again but the libs folder is still empty.

Comment: No I meant type the command "yarn install" in this folder

Comment: Did that as well multiple times, also removed the lock files as I found that tip in some posts. But still `success Already up-to-date.` and still empty libs folder

Comment: okay. do you have a multi-layer tired application or which project type do you use? I have faced this issue sometimes but I was always able to resolve it with use the command yarn or npm install in  the folder. I will try to reproduce the issue with the same template do you use.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I put it in a [public repo](https://github.com/dennisrahmen/DR.DIAS). I used this cli command `abp new DR.DIAS -u blazor -dbms MySQL --separate-auth-server --theme basic --pwa -csf`

Comment: Add this line     "@abp/aspnetcore.mvc.ui.theme.leptonxlite": "~3.0.1"  to you dependencies in the authServer package.json. Then execute abp install-libs again. Now it will work.

Comment: It works, thank you very much! Probably because I selected the "basic" theme. I will open an issue on GitHub for this.

Comment: I am always glad to help a member of the ABP community. Yes this could probably cause the issue. I have created a answer, maybe it will help others they face this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others they will faces this issue:

If the `abp install-libs` command or the `yarn install`command does not work for the installation of the libs check the **package.json** of the project in question:

```
"dependencies": {
"restore": "^0.3.0",
"@abp/aspnetcore.mvc.ui.theme.leptonxlite": "~3.0.1"}
```

The file should contain at least the entry for the used theme(Amount of entries depends on the amount of used modules). In this case the theme entry `"@abp/aspnetcore.mvc.ui.theme.leptonxlite": "~3.0.1"` was missing.